# Symfony2 get non related many-to-many Users in Group

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have User and Group Entities with many to many association using Doctrine in Symfony2 project.
I have successfully get associated Users with Group in form builder like this:

```
$builder->add('members', 'entity', array(
 'class'         => 'TesarUserBundle:User',
 //....
 'query_builder' => function(\Tesar\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository $er ) use ($options) {
  return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
  ->leftJoin('a.groups', 'u')
  ->where('u.id = :id')
  ->setParameter('id', "3");
 }
));
```

This just make a leftJoin on Users with Groups with id 3.

---

I have problems selecting NON associated Users with Group id 3. My code so far:

```
//...
return $er->createQueryBuilder("a")
  ->leftJoin( 'a.groups', 'g', Expr\Join::WITH, 'g.id = :group_id')
  ->where('g.id IS NULL')
  ->setParameter('group_id', "3");
//...
```

I found out, that if there is one User in both Groups, User is included in output, which is not what I want. (have two groups for testing and many Users) 
How can I select Users, that are NOT associated to my Group with id 3?

---

### EDIT:

Based on [maches](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4519047/maches) answer, I rewrite my query builder and everything seems to work fine.

```
return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')        
->select("u")
->from("TesarUserBundle:User","u")
->leftJoin('u.groups g WITH g.id = :groupId', false)
->where(":groupId NOT MEMBER OF u.groups")
->setParameter('groupId', "2");
```

My "where IS NULL" wasn't really working. NOT MEMBER OF does the trick. If someone come up with better solution, please comment. Not sure if it is following best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function findWithoutParameter($pid) 
{
    return  $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT c"
                    . " FROM AmoMainBundle:Company c "
                    . "WHERE ?1 NOT MEMBER OF c.params ")
            ->setParameter(1,$pid)->getResult();
}
```

Without QB, but works with many to many in my case. Function from my Repository. 
[Doc of DQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)